# Ubuntu 14.04.1 locale problem

Tags: 14.04, locale

Why does `locale` still throws me the errors below?

```
root@ubuntu:~# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

This is my `/etc/default/locale`

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US:"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

This is `locale -a`

```
root@ubuntu:~# locale -a
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
```

Have tried rebooting and relogging in, but it doesn't seem to pick up the settings in `/etd/default/locale`.

Comment: Please, do not edit the question to post a solution. Add it as an answer instead and mark it accepted.

Comment: Sure, have moved my solution to the answer section. But I can only accept the answer after 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

After more searching and experimenting with `/etc/environment`, I realize PAM authorization may have something to do with it.

I had the line `UsePAM no` in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
Revert it back to default which is `UsePam yes` and Ubuntu starts to pick up the changes in `/etc/default/locale` and `/etc/environment` again.
So the settings in `/etc/default/locale` actually worked.